# Append a vector of values to key-value lists in R

Tags: r, list

I am looking to append values within a for-loop to a key-value list.

I have 2 lists containing dates and a for loop that checks for if each of the dates within the first list falls between a pair of dates from both lists. The outer loop takes care of constructing the lists and defining the intervals.

Here's the inner for-loop code:

```
for(j in 1:length(Dates)){

   ifelse(Dates[j] %within% int, 
   Concurrent[[ key ]] <- append(case[i], case[j]), 
   No_Conc[[ key ]] <- append(case[i], case[j])

}
```

I think the important code lines here are the `append` statements. My values I am looking for are being replaces by last 2 values. However, I would like to be able append values to the corresponding key in the list.

In python, this is how it would be done.

```
list1 = [123, 234, 456]
d = {'a': [], 'b': []}

for(i in range(list1){
   d['a'].append(list1[i])
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you are asking. I'm sure better answers will come along, but to give you something to work with sooner, try something like the following. It may not work because I don't have data to work with.

```
for(j in 1:length(Dates)){

ifelse(Dates[j] %within% int, 
Concurrent[[ key ]] <- (case[i], case[j]), 
No_Conc[[ key ]] <- (case[i], case[j])

if (i==1 & j==1)
   ret <- Concurrent[[key]]
   ret2<- No_Conc[[key]]
else
   ret <- data.frame(rbind(ret,Concurrent[[key]])
   ret2 <- data.frame(rbind(ret2, No_Conc[[key]])
}
```

Comment: Please upvote the question if you find it appropriate and relevant to the community.